# How to send response through ajax from servlet back to jsp?

Tags: java

This question has been asked many a times. But i got the common answer i.e to send the response through `response.getwriter().write("....")` inside servlet. But it is not the actual way of sending response through ajax. I want to update a `<div>` through the response not the whole page. But I didn't find solution to this. My code is as follows :-

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="jquery.js" ></script>
<form name="myForm" method="post" id="search" action="al">
<input type="text" name="fname"/>
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="button1"/>
</form>

<div id="some">

</div>
<script>
$("#myForm").submit(function(e)
        {
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(response) 
                {
                $("#some").text(response);
                    //console.log(response);
                    //data: return data from server
                },
                error: function(response) 
                {
                    //if fails      
                }
            });e.preventDefault();});


});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

AddressLocator.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String name=request.getParameter("fname");
        //response.getWriter().println("abc.html");
        //response.sendRedirect("getData");
        URL oracle = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+name);
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            response.getWriter().write(inputLine);
        in.close();

    }
```

Here, al is mapped to AddressLocator class.
Please help...thanx in advance..

Comment: In your `success` Ajax handler, use `$(div).html(theNewHtml)` to update the contents of the div.

Comment: But..response.getWriter() is not forwarding the response to jsp again..so how can I handle the response?

Comment: You handle the response in your `success` Ajax handler. It should appear in the `response` variable there. Maybe take a look at some Ajax or jQuery tutorials first.

Comment: i tried what u said but no use..